# How do I draw the force field lines of an isotropic oscillator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, oscillators, vector-fields

In general, how do I draw the force field lines (in the sense of Faraday, i.e. continuous curves whose tangents give the directions and the density of lines give the intensity of the field) of a central force field growing with distance? As a particular example, how do I draw the force field lines of an isotropic oscillator, $\vec F=-kr\hat r$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Draw it like segmented sun rays with longer ray segments at farther distances, arrows pointing inward.

Comment: I understood what you said but I meant in the sense of Faraday, i.e. continuous curves whose tangents give the directions and the density of lines give the intensity of the field. I am stuck with the intensity.

Answer (score 1):

Qualitative drawing:___________________

Sorry, I've mistaken. it should be:

[image]

Comment: I don't agree with this. the end of a field line should be a source. Which is not the case.

Comment: @user115652 but the density at the source should be zero, since it is the point where r = 0, so no field line should be drawn.

Comment: should be *near zero